# Adding points to represent non-chosen locations?

Tags: arcpy

I am looking for a way to set up a discrete choice model in ArcGIS for foraging behavior of individuals, in a grid of 15 locations. To do that I need a point for every possible choice they could have made, currently I only have data for the choice they did make. Right now my data looks a little like this:

```
IndivID    Date    LocationID   X    Y
    1      1/1         1       ...  ...
    1      1/2         4       ...  ...
    1      1/3         3       ...  ...
    1      1/4         2       ...  ...
    1      1/5         3       ...  ...
    1      1/6         1       ...  ...
    1      1/7         2       ...  ...
```

And what I am looking for would be like this (assuming I have 4 locations, and 0 is the choice to not forage for that day).

```
IndivID    Date    LocationID   X    Y    Choice
    1      1/1         0       ...  ...      0
    1      1/1         1       ...  ...      1
    1      1/1         2       ...  ...      0
    1      1/1         3       ...  ...      0
    1      1/1         4       ...  ...      0
    1      1/2         0       ...  ...      0
    1      1/2         1       ...  ...      0
    1      1/2         2       ...  ...      0
    1      1/2         3       ...  ...      0
    1      1/2         4       ...  ...      1
```

I know I would add the Choice field before adding new points and calculate it as 1, so as I add new points I can see what the original choice was, and I have X,Y coordinates for the centroids of each location and a home location I can use to spatially locate the new points, but I am not sure how to go about adding in the extra points to represent the non-chosen options. To give you an idea of the size of my dataset, I have 57 individuals and I am doing this analysis for an entire year (365 days), and actually have 15 sites (used 4 as an example).

Anyone have any ideas how I would go about setting this up, or do you think this type of process is out of the range of ArcGIS's capabilities?

I am specifically looking for an alternative to toiling away at an excel or csv file to make the points, so it can be tweaked and reapplied if I refine the location choices to more smaller plots.

Comment: What are 'non-chosen' points?  How do they relate to 'chosen' points?  I don't have any context so it just sounds arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, I have divided a foraging ground into 15 locations/sites. For each individual each day I currently have the data for the site they chose (visited). To perform a discrete choice analysis I need points for every possible choice. So for each individual each day, I need a point to represent not foraging, and then 1 for each site it did not chose. Basically 16 points per individual per day.

Comment: And the 'sites' are polygons I assume -- if the sites aren't changing why not take the centroid of the polygon to represent it as a point location.  You could use a `SelectByLocation` based on the point that you DO have (chosen) and assume all other points are 'not chosen'.

Comment: Yes I created centroids for each polygon, but I still need a point representing each site for every individual for every day. So I would need to somehow duplicate my layer with site points 20,805 times (but keep them in the same layer), somehow assign each set to an individual ID, then erase the duplicates (generic site points from chosen points). It is unfortunately the only way to perform the discrete choice analysis I am looking to do.

Comment: Create a table of *all* sites (easy in Excel or by using any kind of point grid generator add-on), join the table of data to it, and let the joined values override the original ones.

Comment: Yeah, I was specifically looking for an alternative to Excel because I will be altering the number and size of the location sites in the future. Especially because going through an assigning the individual IDs will be very tedious, they are non-sequential and don't start at 1.